# MySQL JOIN - json returns data only from one table

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a small problem with JSON returning only data from one table when put through ajax on frontend without **userName** that's coming from **Users** table. Backend looks fine when checked with var_dump:

```
/home/maciek/Workspace/Communic/public/admin/privMessage.php:11:
     array (size=3)
      0 => 
        object(Privatemessage)[6]
          private 'id' => string '4' (length=1)
          private 'senderId' => string '2' (length=1)
          private 'receiverId' => string '1' (length=1)
          private 'creationDate' => string '2017-06-28 23:49:15' (length=19)
          private 'text' => string 'asdasdasda' (length=10)
          private 'readStatus' => string '1' (length=1)
          **private 'userName' => string 'stefan' (length=6)**
```

MySQL query (executes properly alone and returns desired result - username is included in the result):

```
SELECT p.*, u.username FROM PrivateMessage p RIGHT JOIN Users u ON p.sender_id=u.id WHERE receiver_id=:receiver_id
```

method in class **Privatemessage** that uses the query:

```
    static public function loadAllRcvdPrvMsgsByUserId(PDO $pdo, $receiverId) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT p.*, u.username FROM PrivateMessage p RIGHT JOIN Users u ON p.sender_id=u.id WHERE receiver_id=:receiver_id");
    $result = $stmt->execute([
        'receiver_id' => $receiverId
    ]);

    $rcvdPrvMsgsArray = [];

    if ($result === true && $stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {

            foreach ($row as $dbPrvMessage) {
                $loadedPrvMsg = new Privatemessage($pdo);
                $loadedPrvMsg->id = $dbPrvMessage->id;
                $loadedPrvMsg->senderId = $dbPrvMessage->sender_id;
                $loadedPrvMsg->receiverId = $dbPrvMessage->receiver_id;
                $loadedPrvMsg->creationDate = $dbPrvMessage->privatemessage_datetime;
                $loadedPrvMsg->text = $dbPrvMessage->privatemessage_text;
                $loadedPrvMsg->readStatus = $dbPrvMessage->privatemessage_readstatus;
                $loadedPrvMsg->userName = $dbPrvMessage->username;

                $rcvdPrvMsgsArray[] = $loadedPrvMsg;
            }
        }
        return $rcvdPrvMsgsArray;
    }
    return null;
}
```

js ajax:

```
    function getReceivedPrivateMsg() {
    $
        .ajax({
            url: '../../../rest/rest.php/privateMessage',
            type: 'GET'
        })
        .done(function (response) {

            console.log(response.success);

        })
        .fail(function (error) {
            console.log('Create sent private message error', error);
        });
}
```

console.log(response.success); in ajax returns the below in Chrome dev console (again, **userName** is missing):

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

> EDIT: I've implemented JsonSerializable in Privatemessage class and forgot to return userName in jsonSerialize() method within the class.

Comment: You're creating an instance of a class named Privatemessage, does this class have a property named $username?

Comment: Gosh, I've implemented JsonSerializable in Privatemessage class and forgot to return userName in it. Thanks! :)

Comment: As an aside, nobody ever uses right join

Comment: That's true, I was thinking this somehow relates to MySQL query itself only to find out I forgot to return userName from jsonSerialize().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class Privatemessage may need to have a public $username property in order for this to work.  It depends on how you've implemented the JSON conversion.  From the comment, it seems like you're using JsonSerializable, so you'd need to make sure all present fields are accounted for in the jsonSerialize method.

---

Looking at your code, if the goal is just to generate a JSON response, I don't see the point of creating an instance of Privatemessage here.  Why don't you just use the existing objects returned from PDO?

```
return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```